# How to download multiple files in local system using POST API request in robot framework rather than in binary form data

Tags: python-requests, robotframework, python-requests-html

I struck in one scenario in which i need to download multiple files in local repository using POST API request in robot framework.

I tried below code but not able to resolve the issue.

```
  ${headers}=  Create Dictionary   Accept=${aster}    Host=api.demosite.com    Connection=keep-alive    Content-Type=${accept}    Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br    User-Agent=${user_agent}
 ${response}=    ExtendedHTTPLibrary.POST On Session    Global    ${resultfiles}    headers=${headers}    json=${demo_body}    stream=${False}
 log    ${response.content}    level=TRACE
 copy files    ${response}    ${EXECDIR}/Logs
```

When i used above code it gives me some binary stream which i am not able to understand.Something like below:

> �9BBi��HI�d(������%E�i�
> ��M��<�^,;��������:��\�{|�}�k���^��{�<��G�#�����7��!�ou����u��7Q��_j�&gl���Sc�I�
> P��é�lT�
> �5��1{w�c.>�v�����=����mok�A��r����0�����I��y���9�8�
> <��1���Lʥ�����q�N��1x0�89�CF���1�'����G8I�q���.G���<�$�Q���͓y�~���G�S��ţ�G���O�[m�(

In **postman** we have that option to **SEND and DOWNLOAD** files and through that i am able to download multiple files in zip folder in my local system.
[image]

My questions are :

1. How to download multiple files in local system or directory using robot framework through POST API request rather than binary stream ?
2. How to achieve task through robot code which postman UI is providing through **SEND and DOWNLOAD** option ?

Below scenario is expected :

1. Fire POST API request
2. DOWNLOAD Files through response of POST API
3. STORE files in local directory.